# Google API: request Additional Scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api, scopes

How can I add scopes to an existing access token? If I read this page correctly, it is possible to do that:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/incremental-auth

But I am having troubles understanding how to implement that. In theory, I should be able to call:

```
gapi.auth.signIn({ 'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts' });
```

... but the documentation on that page says "Later, when your user wants to perform an action that requires additional scopes, your app requests those additional scopes and the user is shown a consent screen and asked to authorize only the new scopes."

So I have a javascript function that I trigger to make that gapi call, and... nothing. Obviously I'm not understanding how to make this work. Is this call supposed to expand the capabilities of my access token, so that next time I use the refresh token to get it, the new scopes will be in place? That doesn't seem to be happening. Any guidance appreciated.

andy

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin', /** Default value **/
scope: 'profile' });                /** Base scope **/
```

Wherever additional scopes are needed, request them by constructing an options builder with the scopes you want to add and then calling user.grant({scope: [OPTIONS BUILDER]})

```
var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
    {'scope': 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'});

googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
googleUser.grant(options).then(
function(success){
  console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
},
function(fail){
  alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
});
```

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) for more info

Comment: I am doing this in react, are we declaring a new variable googleUser, or are we assuming that there is a window.googleUser already declared? does this google user need to exist outside the closure of the block its contained in?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I fixed up the page-level metadata, and my manually triggered call to the gapi.auth.signin function did indeed bring up the window to ask for more permissions.

Comment: note: both the client_id and cookie-policy are required in the page-level metadata, though it's not specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using react and so I didnt have auth2 in the global namespace, just window.gapi so I had to make the following alterations to get the auth2 instance.

```
var auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
var googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get()    

googleUser.grant(options).then(
  function(success) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
  },
  function(fail){
    alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
  });
```